# Why is this monkeypatch in pytest not working?

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, pytest-mock

As I am switching from Django to FastAPI, I also need to change tests from unittests to pytests. I build a custom TestAPI class and have test cases as methods, which works fine. However I want to override some functions (not dependencies) which are used in the code in one testcase. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
def test_smoke_me_api(self, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("app.auth.utils.get_user", mock_get_user)

    re = self.c.get("/me/")
```

It doesn't call the `mock_get_user` function, but instead the `get_user` one. According to some docs, I added the monkeypatch to the `setup_class` function of my test class, but this didn't work as this is apparently initialized with one argument only (`self`).

`self.c` is a client, which is a `TestClient` initialized in the `setup_class`.

Minimal example:

app/auth/utils.py

```
def get_user(sub) -> dict:
    re = requests.get(f"https://{API_DOMAIN}/api/v2/users/{sub}")
    return re.json()
```

app/auth/views.py

```
from app.auth.utils import get_user
@router.get("/")
async def me_get(sub: str = Security(auth.verify)) -> dict:
    return get_user(sub)
```

app/test_main.py

```
def mock_get_user(sub = "testing") -> dict:
    return {
        "created_at": "2023-08-15T13:25:31.507Z",
        "email": "test@test.org"
    }

class TestAPI:
    def setup_class(self):
        from app.main import app
        self.c = TestClient(app)

    def test_smoke_me_api(self, monkeypatch):
        monkeypatch.setattr("app.auth.utils.get_user", mock_get_user)
        re = self.c.get("/me/")
```

Comment: This question would be easier to answer with a [mcve] (because, e.g., successful mocking depends on how things are imported).

Comment: @larsks I added a minimal reproducible example. I left it because it is a lot of interdependent code and even with the 3 files given, it is not yet everything needed to run this I suppose. I was hoping that there is some glaring issue with my code, that is easily findable.

Comment: Don't use `from app.auth.utils import get_user` (or otherwise import individual items from a module) if you want monkeypatches to work. Instead, refer to `app.auth.utils.get_user` or even `import app.auth.utils as auth_utils` and then refer to `auth_utils.get_user`; but you need to go through the module to get the updated function.

Comment: This is what larsks was referring to re: "depends on how things are imported".

Comment: Alternately, you could monkeypatch `app.auth.views.get_user` instead of `app.auth.utils.get_user`.

Comment: from what folder are you running the test?
in my case when I use any intelliJ product I need to be on project root that contains a /tests folder. that way the monkeypatch would be able to work with app.module.class.method

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, this is what I've gone with: patching the `views.get_user` instead of the `utils.get_user` . Thanks a lot for your help. If you want to post this as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @JesusWalker Thanks also for your comment, I am using VS Code and run the tests from the same folder the entire project runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in `app.auth.views` you run `from app.auth.utils import get_user`, you're creating a new reference to the original function `get_user` inside the `app.auth.views` module.

Patching `app.auth.utils.get_user` changes the reference *in `app.auth.utils`*, but it leaves `app.auth.views` with the copy it previously made.

There are two general approaches to fixing this:

1. `import` the module, not the function.

   That is to say, do something more like `import app.auth.utils as auth_utils`, then call `auth_utils.get_user()` to refer back *through the namespace* to which you're applying the monkeypatch
2. Monkeypatch the destination, not the source

   That is to say, instead of monkeypatching `app.auth.utils.get_user`, monkeypatch `app.auth.views.get_user()`.